# How to get the values of ul li from list using jquery

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery-ui

I have three lists pending, in-progress and completed. I just want to get the value of pending list which is getting from a dictionary. Because of that I am not able to insert the values in DB. And also want to know how to change the status value when pending task drag and drop into completed list so that the status change into completed in DB.
I went through some solutions as well provided over the Internet but couldn't find the required solution as I'm novice in coding world.

HTML

```
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Pending</h2> <br>
                    <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
                        {% for i in task %}
                        <li class="ui-state-default">{{i.task_name}}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>In Progress</h2> <br>
                    <ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">a</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">b</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">c</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">d</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">e</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Completed</h2> <br>
                    <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">A</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">B</li>
                        <li class="ui-state-highlight">C</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {

    $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "ul"
    });
    $( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        dropOnEmpty: true
    });
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
    } );

$(function () {
     $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").sortable({
         connectWith: "ul",
         update: function (event, ui) {   
            
            var data        = $(ui.droptrue).children("li:first").find('li').val();
            alert(data)   


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url '' %}",
                data: "data",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {


                }
            });

         }
     }).disableSelection();
 });
```

Comment: You cannot call `.val()` on a List Item Object. It can only be used on Form elements. If you are using jQuery UI, they `ui` doe snot have a `droptrue` entry.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things:

1. in you $.ajax as data you send the string "data". Here you should send some json to parse in the backend to save the data to the db or the variable data you assign
2. (if i get your question right) Add to your `<li>` elements the id for that element like `<li class="ui-state-default" data-id="{{i.id}}">{{i.task_name}}</li>`. In your jQuery Code then grab the data-id and send the new status to server

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function sendData(u, d) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: u,
      data: d,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        return data
      },
      error: function(x, s, e) {
        console.log("Ajax Error:", u, s, e);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  function sortUpdate(e, ui) {
    var list = $(e.target);
    var id = list.attr("id");
    var myData = "action=updateList&list=" + id +"&";
    myData += $("li", list).map(function() {
      var val = $(this).text().trim();
      return id + "[]=" + val;
    }).get().join("&");
    console.log("Sending Data To:", "{% url '' %}");
    console.log("Data:", myData);
    sendData("{% url '' %}", myData);
  }

  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.droptrue",
    update: sortUpdate,
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder"
  });
  $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.droptrue",
    dropOnEmpty: false,
    update: sortUpdate
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
h2 {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.column {
  width: 340px;
}

.container ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  list-style: none;
}

.container ul li {
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Pending</h2>
        <ul id="pending" class="sortable droptrue">
          <li id="pending_1" class="ui-state-default">Task 1</li>
          <li id="pending_2" class="ui-state-default">Task 2</li>
          <li id="pending_3" class="ui-state-default">Task 3</li>
          <li id="pending_4" class="ui-state-default">Task 4</li>
          <li id="pending_5" class="ui-state-default">Task 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>In Progress</h2>
        <ul id="progress" class="sortable dropfalse">
          <li id="progress_1" class="ui-state-highlight">a</li>
          <li id="progress_2" class="ui-state-highlight">b</li>
          <li id="progress_3" class="ui-state-highlight">c</li>
          <li id="progress_4" class="ui-state-highlight">d</li>
          <li id="progress_5" class="ui-state-highlight">e</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Completed</h2>
        <ul id="completed" class="sortable droptrue">
          <li id="completed_1" class="ui-state-highlight">A</li>
          <li id="completed_2" class="ui-state-highlight">B</li>
          <li id="completed_3" class="ui-state-highlight">C</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This breaks down some of the operations into smaller functions. This makes them more flexible and easier to use later. The goals I identified were:

- User moves a item in the list, or to another list
- When the list is updated, send the new order to a URL

  - The Url: `"{% url '' %}"`
  - The Value of each is the `task_name`

It wasn't clear what data you wanted to send, so I tried to be overly prepared. Each list now has a more precise ID, each list item also has an ID in case you want to use `serialize` or `toArray` methods.

When data is sent, I build a URL String. For the Pending list, this would be:

- Action: Update List
- List: Pending
- An Array of all the Pending Items: pending[]=Task Name

Your server side script will get all this data.